# Character of group elements of the Lorentz group

Tags: special-relativity, group-theory, representation-theory

I am looking for a reference for the character of the element of the Lorentz group. If the generator the Lorentz transformations is given by $$\Lambda = e^{i\alpha\cdot J-\beta\cdot K}$$, then I wish to know the character of the representation. I am expecting something like trace of $$D^{j, b}_{m, m'}(\Lambda) = \langle j,m'; b |e^{i\alpha\cdot J-\beta\cdot K}|j,m; b\rangle$$ where $j, m$ labels the angular momentum eigenstates and $b$ the boost eigenstates. Is there a reference that can help me with this?

Comment: Rossmann, Wulf (2002), Lie Groups – An Introduction Through Linear Groups, Oxford Graduate Texts in Mathematics, Oxford Science Publications, ISBN 0-19-859683-9

Comment: @CosmasZachos Which page or Chapter?

Comment: No specifics. Sets up the picture as in [WU](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_the_Lorentz_group_(for_undergraduate_students_of_physics)) or [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_the_Lorentz_group). The group is non-compact, and the unitary infinite-dim reps are very different from the non-unitary finite-dim reps.

Comment: @CosmasZachos So, the characters of such a group is not defined?

Comment: Depends on the representation as you know from SU(2). What are you doing with it?

Comment: @CosmasZachos Just trying it as an exercise in my group theory concepts. I want to verify my computations.

Comment: Tried tracing the 4d [typical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_the_Lorentz_group#Explicit_formulas) boost and rotation?

Comment: @CosmasZachos Yes but that is just for the vector representation corresponding to $j =1$. As I asked in the question I am look for character of general $j$.